# This Year WTD and Last Yeat WTD(4-5-4 Calendar date) data in MSSQL

Tags: sql-server

This Query is for This week should be Sunday - Saturday.
I usually pull data next day, so when I run this report, always will be next day.

```
SELECT MAX(te.StoreID)                                                                                    AS StoreID, 
                                   SUM(te.Price * te.Quantity)                                                                        AS Sales, 
                                   SUM(te.Cost * te.Quantity)                                                                         AS Cost,  
                                   COUNT(DISTINCT t.TransactionNumber)                                                                AS Trxn,
                                   SUM(te.Quantity)                                                                                   AS Quantity 
                            FROM   TransactionEntry te 
                                   INNER JOIN [Transaction] t 
                                           ON te.TransactionNumber = t.TransactionNumber 
                                              AND te.StoreID = t.StoreID 
                                   LEFT JOIN item i 
                                          ON te.itemID = i.ID 
                                   LEFT JOIN Department d 
                                          ON i.DepartmentID = d.ID 
                            WHERE  d.ID <> 8 
                                   AND CONVERT(date, t.Time) >= dateadd(day, 1-datepart(dw, getdate()), convert(date, getdate()))
                                   AND CONVERT(date, t.Time) <= dateadd(day, 8-datepart(dw, getdate()), convert(date, getdate()))
                                   --DATEDIFF(week, t.Time, GETDATE()) = 2
                            GROUP  BY te.StoreID
```

Here's the Last year same week (4-5-4 calendar date)
This data should be(if I pull data today) pulling June 19th 2016 data.
If I pull data tomorrow, i should have data for 6/19/2016 - 6/20/2016 data.

```
SELECT MAX(te.StoreID)                                                                                    AS StoreID, 
                                   SUM(te.Price * te.Quantity)                                                                        AS Sales, 
                                   SUM(te.Cost * te.Quantity)                                                                         AS Cost, 
                                   COUNT(DISTINCT t.TransactionNumber)                                                                AS Trxn, 
                                   SUM(te.Quantity)                                                                                   AS Quantity 
                            FROM   TransactionEntry te 
                                   INNER JOIN [Transaction] t 
                                           ON te.TransactionNumber = t.TransactionNumber 
                                              AND te.StoreID = t.StoreID 
                                   LEFT JOIN item i 
                                          ON te.itemID = i.ID 
                                   LEFT JOIN Department d 
                                          ON i.DepartmentID = d.ID 
                            WHERE  d.ID <> 8 
                               AND CONVERT(date, t.Time) >= dateadd(day, 2-datepart(dw, DateAdd(year,-1,getdate())), convert(date, DateAdd(year,-1,getdate())))
                               AND CONVERT(date, t.Time) <= dateadd(day, 9-datepart(dw, DateAdd(year,-1,getdate())), convert(date, DateAdd(year,-1,getdate())))
                            GROUP  BY te.StoreID
```

Can anyone help me why my data are incorrect????

Thank you in advanced!

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. It is not clear to me what you are trying to do here. I would suggest using a calendar table for these kinds of things. I would also suggest you check out this article (http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to help improve your question.

Comment: If you are doing things with weeks, than you probably need @@DATEFIRST